# Summarising with purr or map the percentage of the total of a factor variable

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to do a map function for each of the variables of a list. To do this function, I want to group_by by some categories and show the percentage of the total of each factor of a variable

For instance, I have this list:

```
mtcars_list <- c ("am","gear","carb")
```

I have the variable I want to group_by for: "cyl" And the variable I want to summarise. In this case I will transform the variable "vs" of the mtcars database as a factor:

```
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs , levels=c('0', '1'))
```

I then do this map:: purr function, which gives me error when I use count, prop.table or similar when summarising...

```
purrr::map(mtcars_list, ~ mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, .data[[.x]]) %>%
  summarise(count(vs), .groups = "drop")*100)
```

When I run this it says:

no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')

The result would be something like this

First category

```
   0        1
A 17.7%     83.3%
B  5.0%     95.5%
```

```
Second category 
    0        1 
A   2.0     98.0
B   4.0     96.0
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Get something working with a single variable before you try to `map` it. `mtcars %>%  group_by(cyl, am) %>%  summarise(count(vs), .groups = "drop")*100` gives errors - `count()` isn't meant to be used inside `summarise`, `count()` expects a data frame as the first argument not just a column. Neither `count` nor `summarize()` or `count()` produce the output like you show in a wide format. I would focus on getting the output you want just for the `am` grouping, and only when you have that working try to `map` over multiple variables.

Comment: We can get rid of the errors in your code with `mtcars %>%  group_by(cyl, am) %>%  count(vs)`, but this gives raw counts (not proportions) so `* 100` won't get you a percentage, and it is not in the wide format you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this is the expected output

```r
df1 <- purrr::map(mtcars_list, ~ mtcars %>% select(cyl,vs,!!sym(.x)) %>% 
                    mutate(n=n() , .by=c(cyl, .data[[.x]], vs)) %>% 
                    mutate(n2=n(), .by=c(cyl, .data[[.x]]) ) %>% 
                    group_by(cyl, .data[[.x]], vs) %>% 
                    slice_tail(n=1) %>% 
                    mutate(perc=(n/n2)*100) %>% 
                    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(cyl,.data[[.x]]), names_from = vs, values_from = perc)
)

df1



[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   cyl, am [6]
    cyl    am   `1`   `0`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     0 100    NA  
2     4     1  87.5  12.5
3     6     0 100    NA  
4     6     1  NA   100  
5     8     0  NA   100  
6     8     1  NA   100  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   cyl, gear [8]
    cyl  gear   `1`   `0`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     3   100    NA
2     4     4   100    NA
3     4     5    50    50
4     6     3   100    NA
5     6     4    50    50
6     6     5    NA   100
7     8     3    NA   100
8     8     5    NA   100

[[3]]
# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   cyl, carb [9]
    cyl  carb   `1`   `0`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     1 100    NA  
2     4     2  83.3  16.7
3     6     1 100    NA  
4     6     4  50    50  
5     6     6  NA   100  
6     8     2  NA   100  
7     8     3  NA   100  
8     8     4  NA   100  
9     8     8  NA   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dplyr` code doesn't work. For the output format you want, the base R functions `table` and `prop.table` get you there faster:

```
purrr::map(
  mtcars_list, \(x) 
  (table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars[[x]]) |> prop.table(margin = 1)) * 100
)
# [[1]]
#            0        1
#   4 27.27273 72.72727
#   6 57.14286 42.85714
#   8 85.71429 14.28571
# 
# [[2]]
#             3         4         5
#   4  9.090909 72.727273 18.181818
#   6 28.571429 57.142857 14.285714
#   8 85.714286  0.000000 14.285714
# 
# [[3]]
#             1         2         3         4         6         8
#   4 45.454545 54.545455  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
#   6 28.571429  0.000000  0.000000 57.142857 14.285714  0.000000
#   8  0.000000 28.571429 21.428571 42.857143  0.000000  7.142857
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gregor Thomas, It will be useful for other things though it's not exactly what I was looking for. I was looking for the percentages per row (as the answer provided by jkatam). But thank you very much.  Do you know how could I give a title to each of the categories instead of [[1]]. Thank you!

Comment: You can set `margin = 1` in `prop.table` to make it row-proportionate.

Comment: Edited to make it row-proportions.